# Need to make code all modular. Goal is to calculate gross and bonus pay contributions based on user input

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, global-variables

```
#global variable
CONTRIBUTION_RATE = 0.05

def main():
    #if these are set to 0 they do not calculate contribution but it does run the program.
    grossPay = 0
    bonusPay = 0

    #gets gross pay from input
    GetGrossPay(grossPay)

    #gets bonus pay from input
    GetBonusPay(bonusPay)     

    #takes input from GetGrossPay to calculate contrib
    showGrossPayContrib(grossPay)

    #takes input from GetBonusPay to calculate contrib
    showBonusContrib(bonusPay)

    #This will prompt user to enter gross pay
def GetGrossPay(grossPay):
    grossPay = float(input("Enter the total gross pay: "))
    return grossPay

    #This will prompt user to enter bonus pay
def GetBonusPay(bonusPay):
    bonusPay = float(input("Enter the total bonus pay: "))
    return bonusPay

    #This SHOULD take the grossPay from GetGrossPay module to get GrossPayContrib
def showGrossPayContrib(theGrossPay):
    theGrossPay = CONTRIBUTION_RATE * theGrossPay
    print("The contribution for the gross pay is $ ",theGrossPay)

    #This SHOULD take the bonusPay from GetBonusPay module to get BonusContrib   
def showBonusContrib(theBonus):
    theBonus = CONTRIBUTION_RATE * theBonus
    print("The contribution for the bonuses is $ ",theBonus)

main()
```

Comment: can you format your code? it's almost impossible to help you with the way the text is hurting my eyes...

Comment: Hi Alina, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask].

Comment: Alina... Only thing missing in your code is that it is not catching value in main which is return from the other functions. Please check this link for help https://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex21.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be what you're looking for. Try this

```
#global variable
CONTRIBUTION_RATE = 0.05

def main():
    gross = GetGrossPay()
    bonus = GetBonusPay()
    sum = GetSumContribution(gross, bonus)
    showGrossPayContrib(gross)
    showBonusContrib(bonus)
    showSumContrib(sum)


def GetGrossPay():
    #as it stands there is no reason to pass a variable in
    return float(input("Enter the total gross pay: "))

def GetBonusPay():
    return float(input("Enter the total bonus pay: "))

def GetSumContribution(gross, bonus):
    return sum((gross*CONTRIBUTION_RATE, bonus*CONTRIBUTION_RATE))

def showGrossPayContrib(theGrossPay):
    theGrossPay = CONTRIBUTION_RATE * theGrossPay
    print("The contribution for the gross pay is $ ",theGrossPay)

def showBonusContrib(theBonus):
    theBonus = CONTRIBUTION_RATE * theBonus
    print("The contribution for the bonuses is $ ",theBonus)

def showSumContrib(sumContrib):
    print("The sum of the Bonus and Gross contributions is ${}".format(sumContrib))

main()
```

Comment: Yes! THANK YOU, Okay I will apply this example to my next scenario and will update if I need further assistance! You really helped me out!!

Comment: Okay so I do need help in my next scenario. I'll still use the example above. If I wanted to find the sum of the contributions from both the gross and bonus how would I be able to add that module in there?

Comment: @Alina Updated, let me know if i understood correctly

Comment: Your first edit was fine, it would prompt to enter gross and bonus pay. When the program would run, it would output the contributions for each. How would I display in order: input gross pay, input bonus pay, output gross contrib, output bonus contrib, output contribution sum of gross and bonus (this is the only missing part). How would I take values that the gross pay contrib and bonus pay contrib modules calculated to add them together into it's own module?

Comment: @Alina Updated!

Comment: I ran the program but, it seems to be adding gross and bonus instead of their contributions.

Comment: @Alina So sorry just realized what you meant!

Comment: Not a problem! I have no one to answer my questions. My teacher won't answer syntax questions and classmates have not replied to my emails. You're honestly the only one that can help me.

Comment: @Alina That's what SO is here for! Does the code work as expected?

Comment: I will update you when I can. I had to step away from my computer. I really appreciate all your help!

Comment: Yes, It did work! Although I can't apply it to my next scenario. How would I divide two variables. In the first example you used 'sum' is there something like that to divide

Comment: `sum` is used to take the sum of all items in an `array`. There are operations that can be used to modify immutable objects such as `float` or `int` and you have already used one; `+`. In the same respect you can use `/`, `*`, `-`, and `%`. So if you needed to divide two variables you would use `var1 /= var2` which is the same as `var1 = var1 / var2`. Hope this helps

Comment: I actually figured something out. I was able to cut out bits of code that wasn't needed too! Thanks again for your help!